# Google Cast SDK v3 Reconnection Logic

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, android-cast-api

In Google Cast SDK v3 documentation, it says that the reconnection logic is managed by the framework.
https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/android_migrate_sender#reconnection_logic

And in this part it says that the reconnection functionality is on by default.
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate#automatic_reconnection

In my case, for some devices and in some occasions after disconnect the device from wifi for 10 seconds, it is not able to reconnect again.
Is this behavior expected?

Should the device reconnect to chromecast after the connection was lost for 30 seconds?

Is this documented somewhere? I wasn't able to find it in the documentation.

Thanks.

Comment: it should reconnect. If you can reproduce this with the sample CastVideos-android (v3), then please open a ticket on the sdk issue tracker with details: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list